# How to copy table from one database to another using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to copy a table from one database to another database But no response in server

Here is the command

```
pg_dump -U database_user_name -t categories my_current_db_name | psql new_db_name
```

What wrong in the above code it is not showing any response.

Comment: Does that table already exist in new_db_name?  The dump will generate a table creation script unless you add a flag for content only...

Comment: Perhaps pass `-U database_user_name` to the psql command as well.  Also, can you post the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"` This is the error message but I did not use `root user` in the above syntax

Comment: Perhaps run this as postgres user:  `sudo -u postgres pg_dump -U database_user_name ...`

Comment: If you are running as root (a bad idea), then "psql" without "-U" will try to connect to postgresql as root.

Comment: @jjanes then what is the solution. Is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 2):

If something does not work then divide it into smaller problems.

At first try to run:

```
pg_dump -U database_user_name -t categories my_current_db_name
```

What is it printing? Do you see error message or correct dump output?

Then try to run:

```
psql new_db_name
```

Is it able to connect to database?

Possible problems:

1. `new_db_name` does not exists
2. you cannot connect with source or destination database because of wrong user/password/db host/port